# Ionic Framework with Backand doesn't work on device as on Ripple (emulator)

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, backand

So, I'm trying to learn Ionic Framework, but, I've got a problem already, I'm running the Ionic Backand Starter app (like an example app) and I've got two different results when testing it.
Ripple: When I run it from VS on Ripple, it works perfectly fine, the Database is how it is supposed to be, everything is running fine.
Device: When I run it from VS on my Android Device (Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini, without root), the application has a problem when loading the Backand Database. It looks completely empty.

Im going to leave prints of the 2 trials and also my Controller.js, App.js and Services.js, also, I'm leaving the github project link, in case you want more detailed stuff.

**GitHub Project:**
[GitHub Backand Ionic Starter Project](https://github.com/backand/backand-ionic-starter)

**Prints:**
Device: http://prntscr.com/a3iq45
Ripple: http://prntscr.com/a3iqgd

***CODES:***

*App.js:*

```
    // Ionic template App
 // angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
 // 'SimpleRESTIonic' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('SimpleRESTIonic', ['ionic', 'backand', 'SimpleRESTIonic.controllers', 'SimpleRESTIonic.services'])

    .run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
                StatusBar.styleLightContent();
            }
        });
    })
    .config(function (BackandProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

        BackandProvider.setAppName('ionicstarter'); // change here to your app name
        BackandProvider.setSignUpToken('4ce88904-75c5-412c-8365-df97d9e18a8f'); //token that enable sign up. see http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/security/index.html#sign-up
        BackandProvider.setAnonymousToken('87c37623-a2d2-42af-93df-addc65c6e9ad'); // token is for anonymous login. see http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/security/index.html#anonymous-access

        $stateProvider
            // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
            .state('tab', {
                url: '/tabs',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
            })
            .state('tab.dashboard', {
                url: '/dashboard',
                views: {
                    'tab-dashboard': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dashboard.html',
                        controller: 'DashboardCtrl as vm'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('tab.login', {
                url: '/login',
                views: {
                    'tab-login': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-login.html',
                        controller: 'LoginCtrl as login'
                    }
                }
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tabs/dashboard');

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('APIInterceptor');
    })

    .run(function ($rootScope, $state, LoginService, Backand) {

        function unauthorized() {
            console.log("user is unauthorized, sending to login");
            $state.go('tab.login');
        }

        function signout() {
            LoginService.signout();
        }

        $rootScope.$on('unauthorized', function () {
            unauthorized();
        });

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {
            if (toState.name == 'tab.login') {
                signout();
            }
            else if (toState.name != 'tab.login' && Backand.getToken() === undefined) {
                unauthorized();
            }
        });

    })
```

*Controller.js:*

```
angular.module('SimpleRESTIonic.controllers', [])

.controller('LoginCtrl', function (Backand, $state, $rootScope, LoginService) {
    var login = this;

    function signin() {
        LoginService.signin(login.email, login.password)
            .then(function () {
                onLogin();
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    function anonymousLogin(){
        LoginService.anonymousLogin();
        onLogin();
    }

    function onLogin(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('authorized');
        $state.go('tab.dashboard');
    }

    function signout() {
        LoginService.signout()
            .then(function () {
                //$state.go('tab.login');
                $rootScope.$broadcast('logout');
                $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
            })

    }

    login.signin = signin;
    login.signout = signout;
    login.anonymousLogin = anonymousLogin;
})

.controller('DashboardCtrl', function (ItemsModel, $rootScope) {
    var vm = this;

    function goToBackand() {
        window.location = 'http://docs.backand.com';
    }

    function getAll() {
        ItemsModel.all()
            .then(function (result) {
                vm.data = result.data.data;
            });
    }

    function clearData(){
        vm.data = null;
    }

    function create(object) {
        ItemsModel.create(object)
            .then(function (result) {
                cancelCreate();
                getAll();
            });
    }

    function update(object) {
        ItemsModel.update(object.id, object)
            .then(function (result) {
                cancelEditing();
                getAll();
            });
    }

    function deleteObject(id) {
        ItemsModel.delete(id)
            .then(function (result) {
                cancelEditing();
                getAll();
            });
    }

    function initCreateForm() {
        vm.newObject = {name: '', description: ''};
    }

    function setEdited(object) {
        vm.edited = angular.copy(object);
        vm.isEditing = true;
    }

    function isCurrent(id) {
        return vm.edited !== null && vm.edited.id === id;
    }

    function cancelEditing() {
        vm.edited = null;
        vm.isEditing = false;
    }

    function cancelCreate() {
        initCreateForm();
        vm.isCreating = false;
    }

    vm.objects = [];
    vm.edited = null;
    vm.isEditing = false;
    vm.isCreating = false;
    vm.getAll = getAll;
    vm.create = create;
    vm.update = update;
    vm.delete = deleteObject;
    vm.setEdited = setEdited;
    vm.isCurrent = isCurrent;
    vm.cancelEditing = cancelEditing;
    vm.cancelCreate = cancelCreate;
    vm.goToBackand = goToBackand;
    vm.isAuthorized = false;

    $rootScope.$on('authorized', function () {
        vm.isAuthorized = true;
        getAll();
    });

    $rootScope.$on('logout', function () {
        clearData();
    });

    if(!vm.isAuthorized){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('logout');
    }

    initCreateForm();
    getAll();

});
```

*Services.js:*

```
angular.module('SimpleRESTIonic.services', [])

.service('APIInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q) {
    var service = this;

    service.responseError = function (response) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized');
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
    };
})

.service('ItemsModel', function ($http, Backand) {
    var service = this,
        baseUrl = '/1/objects/',
        objectName = 'items/';

    function getUrl() {
        return Backand.getApiUrl() + baseUrl + objectName;
    }

    function getUrlForId(id) {
        return getUrl() + id;
    }

    service.all = function () {
        return $http.get(getUrl());
    };

    service.fetch = function (id) {
        return $http.get(getUrlForId(id));
    };

    service.create = function (object) {
        return $http.post(getUrl(), object);
    };

    service.update = function (id, object) {
        return $http.put(getUrlForId(id), object);
    };

    service.delete = function (id) {
        return $http.delete(getUrlForId(id));
    };
})

.service('LoginService', function (Backand) {
    var service = this;

    service.signin = function (email, password, appName) {
        //call Backand for sign in
        return Backand.signin(email, password);
    };

    service.anonymousLogin= function(){
        // don't have to do anything here,
        // because we set app token att app.js
    }

    service.signout = function () {
        return Backand.signout();
    };
});
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It's possible that ripple emulator use cookies from your system, So you are authenticated in Backand. It's not the case in you Phone. Did you try to login in your real device?

Comment: Yes, I've decided to learn Firebase instead of Backand, but still getting the same annoying bug.

Comment: So as long as it's not Backand problem, why did you change to Firebase?

Comment: @DanielNaim I've changed to Firebase because they have better API guides for a starter like me and more tutorials available in internet. 
I guess people with more knowledge about REST APIs and Ionic would not have changed like me, but I can't work with a tool that I can't learn how to use. 
Consider adding more tutorials and API docs in your website and maybe creating video tutorials. I guess the number of new users will raise. 

Ygalbel I've logged in on Backand in my real device but it didn't work neither.